# relationship quadratic program and linear program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

Consider the following quadratic programming problem

$$
\min\limits_{x \in S} f(x) = c^{\text{T}}x + \frac{1}{2}x^{\text{T}}Qx,
$$
where $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex compact set, $Q$ is an $n \times n$ symmetic matrix and $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $x^*$ is the global solution of the above problem. I have found without proof that $x^*$ is also optimal for the linear program $\min\limits_{x \in S} \nabla f(x^*)^{\text{T}}x$? Can someone please provide a proof? What is the intuition behind this result?

Comment: can you write the optimality conditions for both problems?

Comment: For the linear program I know that the global solution is attained at an extreme point. For the quadratic program I can write down the KKT conditions. Is this correct?

Comment: By saying that the quadratic programming solution $x*$ is also the solution for the linear program, are you saying that you solved the exact same objective function (the first formula) with a QP solver, and then an LP solver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use [following theorem](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Eburke/crs/408f/notes/nlp/coc.pdf):

> $P$: $\min f(x)$ subject to $x \in S$

> Theorem 1.1 If $\bar{x}$ is a local solution to the problem $P$, then $f'(\bar{x};d)\leq 0$ for all feasible directions $d$ for $S$ at $\bar{x}$ for which $f'(\bar{x};d)$ exists.

If $x^*$ is optimal for the quadratic problem, then $(c + Q x^*)^Td \leq 0$ for all feasible directions $d$ at $x^*$. For the linear problem, a solution $\bar{x}$ is optimal if $(c + Q x^*)^Td \leq 0$ for all feasible directions $d$ at $\bar{x}$, and it is clear that $\bar{x}=x^*$ satisfies this condition.

Comment: Thank your very much. I have another question. Suppose $S = [0,1]^n$ and $x^*$ is the optimal solution of $P$. When can I fix some variables to $0$ or $1$?

Comment: @Wayne I do not get your question. Why would you fix a variable after finding the optimal solution?

Comment: I have asked a new question. Here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3883570/variable-fixation-for-solving-quadratic-program