# Variable fixation for solving quadratic program

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

I have read the following article: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10898-011-9713-2

The following theorem is stated without proof:

> Let $x^*$ denote the optimal solution of $\min\limits_{x \in [0,1]^n}
>  f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^{\text{T}}Qx + c^{\text{T}}x$, where $Q$ is an $n
>  \times n$ symmetric matrix and $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let
> \begin{align*} l_i &= c_i + \frac{1}{2}q_{ii} + \sum_{j \neq
> > i}\min(0,q_{ij}) \\ u_i &= c_i + \frac{1}{2}q_{ii} + \sum_{j \neq
> > i}\max(0,q_{ij}). \end{align*}
>
> (i) If $l_i > 0$ then $x_i^* = 0$;
>
> (ii) If $u_i < 0$ then $x_i^* = 1$.

They said, that the proof is given by https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02247879

But I can't reconstruct the proof. In the second paper they considered also the problem $\min\limits_{x \in [0,1]^n}
 f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^{\text{T}}Qx + c^{\text{T}}x$. Then they said that variables, whose partial derivatives have fixed sign in $[0,1]^n$ can be forced to $0$ or $1$. First of all: What does is mean to have fixed sign in $[0,1]^n$?

Comment: Fixed sign means that the derivative is always positive (or always negative) for all $x$ in the feasible region. I suspect that the $l_i$ and $u_i$ are ways of checking that.

Comment: How does the bounds on the gradient give me the information when to fix some variables?

Comment: if the gradient is always positive over the feasible region, the objective value increases when the variable gets larger, so you should fix the variable at 0